# Get selected value of a dropdown using jQuery into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have an interface that receives two values from the interface:

One is a date and the other come from a dropdown menu and is a string.

The date value is all right, but the value from the dropdown menu is not.

Is all the time picking the "default" value. I want to pass the value the user is selecting.
So instead of selecting the value the user pick is always taking the

> @Resources.Resources.SelectUser

Which is basically the "pick a user" value.

The code is the following:

```
<div id="employee_info" >
<div class="search_employee" id="search_employee">
        <select name="search_emp" id="search_emp" style="width: 174px">
            @{   
                if (ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee == null || ((IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.ActiveUsersList>)ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee).Count() == 0)
                {
                    //@:<h3>No records were processed.</h3>

                }
                else
                {
                @:
                <option>@Resources.Resources.SelectUser</option> 
                    foreach (var usr in ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee)
                    {     
                <option id="selected_user">@usr.EmployeeName</option>        
                    }
                @:
}
            }
        </select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="datePicker">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>@*@Resources.Resources.Date: *@<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script name="select_date" id="select_date">

  $(function () {
      var userName = $('#search_emp').val();
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          $.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  strUserName: userName,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
</script>
<button class="action" type="button" id="button_select">@Resources.Resources.ButtonFind</button>
```

I also tryied this:

```
 var userName = $('select#search_emp option:selected').val();
```

but I've got the same results.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var userName = $('#search_emp').val();
```

is running when your page loads (within the document.ready function). So then it's storing in the userName variable whatever the selected value is at that moment. When you come to handle your button click, it doesn't update that value from the dropdown. Move that code inside the click event handler and it will get the selected value from the dropdown at that moment in time, not an earlier value.